# Set global variables in vue 3

Tags: vue.js, global-variables, vuejs3

As u will see in the code, i am following vue 3 documentation on how to use global variables in vue 3, https://vuejs.org/api/application.html. This is main.js file:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'jquery/src/jquery.js'

let app = createApp(App)

/* GLOBAL VARIABLES*/
// app.config.globalProperties.$headingMain = 'Direct mail marketing that works'
app.provide('headingMain', 'Direct mail marketing that works')


createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')

import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'
```

Home.vue component:

```html
<template>
  <h1 class="heading">{{ myHeading }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  inject: ["headingMain"],
  data() {
    return {
      myHeading: this.headingMain,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

h1 element wont show here.
This is approach with app.provide and inject. I also tried with app.config.globalProperties, you can see there is a commented line in main.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have two application instances, and you used `provide` on one instance while `inject`-ing from the other instance's child component. The two instances are not connected in any way.

```js
// app instance 1
let app = createApp(App)
app.provide('headingMain', 'Direct mail marketing that works')

// app instance 2 (where the `inject` occurs)
createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```

#### Solution

Use the same application instance to `provide` and `inject`:

```js
let app = createApp(App)
app.provide('headingMain', 'Direct mail marketing that works')

 
app.use(router).mount('#app')
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-provide-inject-2?file=src%2Fmain.js)

Answer (score 3):

```
// 1. Assign app to a variable
let app = createApp(App)

// 2. Assign the global variable before mounting. (here $globalVar is the name of your global variable. you should use the global name that starts with the '$' sign. but it's not compulsory.)
app.config.globalProperties.$globalVar = 'globalVar'

// 3. Use router and mount app
app.use(router).mount('#app')
```

2. if you want to use it in the script then in your component.

> ```
>  <script>
>      export default {
>          data() {
>              return {
>                  myVar: this.$globalVar
>              }
>          }
>      }
>  </script>
> ```

3. if you want direcly in  template than use like,

> ```
>  <template>
>       <h1>{{ $globalVar }}</h1>
>  </template>
> ```